# Feedback on Kivati

Tags: deployment, tools

I would like to have your feedback on Kivati Composite Application Management.

Does somebody have experience with it? 
Is it worth it?

Site : [Kivati](http://www.kivati.com/Pages/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I used Kivati on a global WCM roll-out. I also showed it in a talk at the European SharePoint Best Practices Conference. It's a cool tool - "repeater" concept is good for rolling out updates across large farms. However at the end of the day, it's just generating API code for you - and considering there's a learning curve and a SharePoint developer could just write this code himself, you have to weigh up the advantages.

One thing in it's favour is the UI it presents onto deploying packages - perfect for allowing an admin to specify URLs etc. We used it successfully with a global hoster, their team liked the deployment experience we gave them.